# How to check for error validation for many values when parsing ints and enums

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a mini project and I can't seem to understand how to check for error validation if the user enters a string when trying to parse for int and enums.

I am new to c# and it is taking me quite the hassle to figure out how to make something without making the code big and messy.

This is the example of the values:

```
int.TryParse(coordinates[0], out int x);
int.TryParse(coordinates[1], out int y);
Direction d = (Direction)Enum.Parse(typeof(Direction), coordinates[2]);
//values of startx to be added

int.TryParse(coordinates[3], out int X);
int.TryParse(coordinates[4], out int Y);
Direction D = (Direction)Enum.Parse(typeof(Direction), coordinates[5]);
//values of endx to be added
```

How to make sure the user only enters an int value for x, y, X and Y. and enum values for d and D?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to get when value is not int or enum? Exception? Some message? Close the program?

Comment: It is bassically a while loop that asks for a set of coordinates, and parses the coordinates into the variables. 
I want to be able to send an error message if the user enters something wrong and let the loop start again to when it asks for the coordinates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create 2 simple methods with validations for int and enum values

```
private static int GetIntValue(string text)
{
   if(int.TryParse(text, out int value))
   {
      return value;
   }
   else
   {
     // TODO: action when user enters not int
   }
}

private static Direction GetDirectionValue(string text)
{
   if(Enum.TryParse(text, out Direction value)
   {
      return value;
   }
   else
   {
     // TODO: action when user enters not enum
   }
}
```

and use it

```
int x = GetIntValue(coordinates[0]);
int y = GetIntValue(coordinates[1]);
Direction d = GetDirectionValue(coordinates[2]);

int X = GetIntValue(coordinates[3]);
int Y = GetIntValue(coordinates[4];
Direction D = GetDirectionValue(coordinates[5]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplified method that I usually use when I need to get an integer from the user. It takes in a string "prompt" (the question or request that the user is responding to), and returns an integer. It makes use of a `while` loop that continually calls `Console.ReadLine` to get the user input until `int.TryParse` is successful ([`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) returns true if the input was successfully converted to an `int`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Continually prompts the user for input until they enter a valid integer
/// </summary>
/// <param name="prompt">The question or request to display to the user</param>
/// <returns>The integer value of the user's response</returns>
private static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt)
{
    int value;

    do
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value));

    return value;
}
```

I also use some overloads of this method which take in a minimum and maximum allowed value, a set of valid values, a set of invalid values, and even a method to invoke to validate the input. It also gives a custom error message so the user understands what they need to do to fix the input. You can get pretty tricky with it, but I'll just leave the basic one here for you to start with.

In use, it's simple:

```
int response = GetIntFromUser("Enter your favorite whole number: ");
Console.WriteLine("You entered the number " + response);
```

[image]